# Does Firebase offer a visual way to view and update tabular data?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Does Firebase offer a way to view and update our data in a more human-readable format, rather than large trees of text?

Parse has a great browser for viewing and updating tables of data, which I found invaluable. It was easy to find specific data, and columns had helper menus for creating pointers and references to objects in other objects/tables. It was also easy to translate spreadsheet data into databases of users/places/etc. I guess I'm looking for something similar in Firebase, if it exists.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Firebase is a schemaless database. Since it stores the data as JSON, it offers a visualization of the data as an editable tree in your Firebase Console. It does not offer a table view, although you could easily create that yourself.

Comment: My programming skills are poor, and I mostly want to use Firebase for lightweight prototyping, so I don't think I'll be rolling my own solution.

But if someone out there builds a Parse-like front end for Firebase, I'd pay a pretty penny for it. :)

Comment: How are we supposed to easily locate nodes in a tree that could be tens of thousands of lines long?